# Connect to Exchange server email from thunderbird (alternative to exquilla)

Tags: email, microsoft-exchange, thunderbird

In the organisation I am working, emails are hosted through a microsoft Exchange server. 
In Linux, I used till now Thunderbird together with the plugin exquilla.

I am looking to an alternative to this plugin (or, an alternative to thunderbird itself) to access to my email account (the web access is an option, but I don't like the exchange website interface).

Answer (score 1):

Besides Thunderbird + Lightning, there's Evolution with the `evolution-mapi` or `evolution-ews` extension. This supports at least Exchange 200, 2003, 2007, and probably also 2010.

There are also plenty of articles about this topic in the web, e.g. on [linux.com](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/370590-connect-evolution-to-an-exchange-server), [wiki.ubuntu.com: EvolutionExchange](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EvolutionExchange), and on [superuser: How does one make Evolution work with Exchange 2010?](https://superuser.com/q/98465/317140). I also found a compability list: [Evolution: Who with who (german)](http://www.msxfaq.de/clients/evolution.htm#wer_mit_wem)

To give a more specific answer, more details on your requirements and circumstances are needed.